# Python pip install geopy on MAC OSX, alter Error : geopy-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, macos, pip, geopy

```
pip install ~/Downloads/geopy-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
pip install geopy
```

> DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be
> maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support
> for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be
> found at
> https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
> ERROR: geopy-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel on this
> platform.**

Recently, I use pip to install the geopy, the command alter upon message, but I look in the PyPI, there has a geopy version==2.1.0, it support python=3.x. But I can't install it.
I also try to use .whl to install, but it still alter upon message.
Now I want to know the geopy whether support python=3.x, it makes me self-doubt.

Comment: Why can't you install it?  Did you install Python 3 on your Mac?

Comment: Try `python3 -m pip install geopy`